# Accepting or rejecting the null hypothesis based on 95% confidence interval of mean difference

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

95% confidence interval of mean difference:  (-0.001805385259279729, 0.0020745035498274077)

Should I accept the null hypothesis if the values are so small which are 0 practically?

Comment: So it's the mean difference ... for what? What are you measuring/sampling?

Comment: Percentage in daily return for two different stocks. The context shouldn't matter since I don't think there is a general rule of thumb for this sort of stuff? Or do people say no matter how small the difference is, the null hypothesis should be rejected as long as the value is not 0.